# Any tools for generating sprite sheets for animation using cocos 2D

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite

New to cocos2D.Giving it a try,I found Blender,a tool that can generate sprite sheet.Are there any other free/open source tools for generating/developing/creating sprite sheet?

Comment: can you link the blender that you found?  But texture packer is great

Comment: ok - so from what I understand, Blender is really for exporting out 3D sprite sheets.  The other tools below do not author the sprites, they just make sheets from them, Texture Packer can use flash files also for the source, so flash animations can make sheets too.  But blender is not really made to create generic sprite sheets.

Comment: @nycynik : ok i will look on Texture packet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't live without [Texture Packer](http://texturepacker.com)! It has become almost the standard for cocos2d development. I believe there is a free version which has limited features, I highly recommend the paid version however.

There are lots of great tutorials about it's use. Here is one to get you started.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2361/how-to-create-and-optimize-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d-with-texture-packer-and-pixel-formats

Answer (score 0):

Ahh I have been searching for that kind of tool long time and than I wrote mine https://github.com/hazardland/hazardland.java.sprite